# Serve scaled images solution? Images at external host

Tags: html, css, image, host, gtmetrix

After running GTmetrix speed-test tells me the following: "XYZ image is resized in HTML or CSS from 800x539 to 400x269. Serving a scaled image could save 112.1 KiB (75% reduction)."

My problem is that all my images are hosted in an external server. And im talking about hundreds of images. So resizing/reuploading is not a viable solution, in other words i cannot modify the images.

What would be the most easy/viable solution to implement served scaled images?
Regards!.

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to call a service on your server that resize the image when they are downloaded, obviusly it will slow down the loading of every image and so of your website

Answer (score 0):

Try [Imagekit.io](https://imagekit.io). You can attach your external hosted server as source to imagekit and start serving images via CDN. It has url based transformation and manipulation capabilities which will allow you to dynamically resize the images. It also optimize the images. Since images will be cached on CDN, it won't slow down the website.

Disclaimer: I am Co-Founder of Imagekit.io.